Trying to make a sorted array of the indexes of another array in an extremely limited version of "python"
I'm trying to make a sorting function that will make an array of the indexes of the "input array."
Eg. Array(19,21,15,50,14) would return Array(4,2,0,1,3)
That may sound easy, but the version of "python" I am using is very limited. (Don't ask which or why it's in quotes, that's not the point.) Here are the limitations:

Cannot pass variables through functions (return, and stuff like def func(var2, var1)), but I can use them to change the values of global variables
Cannot use embedded arrays
Cannot use any "pre-built" python functions like sort() or something
Cannot change the values of 2 variables in the same line, e.g. var1,var2 = var2,var1

I'm looking for a way to do this with the lowest time complexity. I feel like I know how to do this with a bubble sort or insertion sort, but the array I'll need to sort is 41 items long...
I've tried to write mergesorts and quicksorts since they have low time complexity but I have no idea how to do them without carrying variables between functions.
If you do come up with an algorithm please write it in python so that I can translate it into my very cool version of python.

41 items is basically nothing. A potato could sort that using a bubble sort instantaneously. Also, I'm curious what Python this is. I've never heard of these limitations before.,

What are "embedded arrays"?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Please read How to ask and answer homework questions. Even if it's not homework, some of the same points apply, like "Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first" and "Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation". See also [ask].

If you post your code, please include the implementation of Array. I'm not clear on how it's different from a list or tuple.

If it helps, NumPy calls this "argsort"

@FreePalestine it's not very readable since the language is fairly different, I just know python and this language well enough to be able to translate between them

@Carcigenicate It's overwatch workshop lol, -> workshop.codes/editor <-. It's not really that similar to python but I know python the best so that's why I asked for python. It gets overwhelmed fairly easily so that's why i've been trying to find a more condensed version.

@wjandrea Array is just a list, the syntax is just weird my bad

But the array is 41 items long.... Even bogosort will work for such a tiny array

@Cincinnatus What do you mean with "work"?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This isn't a [tag:python] question, and the references to Python make it kind of confusing...I don't know what the best approach is, but I don't think it's this.

Either ask the question for Python (or JavaScript, or whatever) without restrictions (and take out the matter of the conversion you'll need to do), or ask the question for the target language. In the latter case, provide links to full language description / documentation. Also include your code attempt and explain where you're stuck.

@nocomment  I mean that the sorting will finish before the heat death of the universe

Based on the question's premises, the array to be sorted is global, like array[].
Declare a global array of indexes: index[]. Sort the indexes according the the values in the global array. Compare would use something like (array[index[i]] <= array[index[j]]). If it is only 41 values, insertion sort should be fast enough, as it is common for library sorts to use insertion sort for groups of 64 values or less due to being cache friendly and also stable (order of equal elements preserved).
You could then reorder index[] and array[] to sort index[] and array[] in O(n) time, if that was to be done later. This is mostly used to sort several arrays according to one of them: sort array1[], array2[], array[3], ..., according to values in array1[].
C++ could do this generically (non-global array) using a template with a lambda compare.
